# use bitsadmin with shortened url

Tags: windows, powershell, internet-explorer, url, cmd

The webpage Im trying to download is located at:

```
bit.ly/nlhtml
```

I want to download the above webpage using an in-built function in cmd; i.e, no wget or curl etc...

The code I tried is:

`bitsadmin /transfer debjob /download /priority normal "bit.ly/nlhtml" "C:\bit\nl.html"`

The above webpage should be saved in html format in folder "bit" in C drive.

The output Im getting for the above command is:

```
BITSADMIN version 3.0
BITS administration utility.
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corp.

Unable to add file - 0x8007010b
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the command flow to get that done.

bitsadmin /create testjob

bitsadmin /addfile testjob "url" "path\to\file.html"

bitsadmin /resume testjob

bitsadmin /info testjob /verbose

... Once state is TRANSFERRED THEN...

bitsadmin /complete testjob

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bits/bitsadmin-examples

Comment: in the second step to add a job Im receiving an error, The code I wrote is bitsadmin /addfile testjob bit.ly/nlhtml c:\nl.html. Can you please check it??

Comment: @Arsalan this worked for me: bitsadmin /addfile testjob https://www.google.com C:\nl.html  
try it without the quotes

Comment: Yeah, I did it without the quotes. Can you please try to use the above link bit.ly\nlhtml and test it??

Comment: @Arsalan I can't/won't on this computer.  Sorry.  Are you able to get this to work with non-shortened urls?

Comment: Nope. The output for each step after the first is same, Found 4 jobs named "testjob". Use job identifier instead of the job name.

Comment: @Arsalan use bitsadmin /reset to reset all those old jobs...have you read the documentation I linked?

Comment: Yup I  did. and resetting doesnt help either.

Comment: C:\Users\pranay kumar>bitsadmin /reset

BITSADMIN version 3.0
BITS administration utility.
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corp.

{AE7830D3-08DB-48DF-B380-FB331734353B} canceled.
1 out of 1 jobs canceled.

C:\Users\pranay kumar>bitsadmin /create testjob

BITSADMIN version 3.0
BITS administration utility.
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corp.

Created job {A081CD2E-FF12-4386-B39A-87A9EB3D85D5}.

C:\Users\pranay kumar>bitsadmin /addfile testjob google.com C:\tj.html

BITSADMIN version 3.0
BITS administration utility.
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corp.

Unable to add file to job - 0x80070057

Comment: @Arsalan you haven't told bitsadmin the protocol you want to use...  it should be http ://url or https ://url  I put spaces in so it wouldn't link it

Comment: BITSADMIN version 3.0
BITS administration utility.
(C) Copyright Microsoft Corp.

GUID: {95850930-911D-4C37-A21F-26B7260F3B58} DISPLAY: 'tj'
TYPE: DOWNLOAD STATE: TRANSIENT_ERROR OWNER: LAPTOP-L1E7FBN7\pranay kumar
PRIORITY: NORMAL FILES: 0 / 1 BYTES: 0 / UNKNOWN
CREATION TIME: 02-11-2018 02:46:54 MODIFICATION TIME: 02-11-2018 02:47:10

Comment: COMPLETION TIME: UNKNOWN ACL FLAGS:
NOTIFY INTERFACE: UNREGISTERED NOTIFICATION FLAGS: 3
RETRY DELAY: 600 NO PROGRESS TIMEOUT: 1209600 ERROR COUNT: 0
PROXY USAGE: PRECONFIG PROXY LIST: NULL PROXY BYPASS LIST: NULL
ERROR FILE:    http:\\www.google.com -> C:\T\tj.html
ERROR CODE:    0x80200068
ERROR CONTEXT: 0x00000005
DESCRIPTION:
JOB FILES:
        0 / UNKNOWN WORKING http:\\www.google.com -> C:\T\tj.html

Comment: NOTIFICATION COMMAND LINE: none
owner MIC integrity level: MEDIUM
owner elevated ?           false

Peercaching flags
         Enable download from peers      :false
         Enable serving to peers         :false

CUSTOM HEADERS: NULL

Comment: @Arsalan This isn't really the place for step by step tech support.  I've given you the proper command sequence. I've verified that it is working on my Windows 10 Box per the documentation I have provided.  I will say though.. that I was having issues getting google to work (because they apparently do not support the range protocol header) but I had no problem with https ://www.ibm.com .